# React; How to get the width of React-Alert adjust based on the alert text

Tags: reactjs, alert

I'n my react app, i'm using `react-alert`. The problem i'm having is the width seems to be fixed thus having the text wrap. I'm trying to have the width adjust it's length based on the length of the containing alert message and not wrap the text. How do i go about doing that?

```
// React Alert
import { Provider as AlertProvider } from "react-alert";
import AlertTemplate from "react-alert-template-basic";

// Alerts Options
const alertOptions = {
  timeout: 5000,
  position: 'top center',
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <Provider store={store}>
      <AlertProvider template={AlertTemplate} {...alertOptions}>
        <App />
      </AlertProvider>
    </Provider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two ways you can get around this:

1. Use your own template instead of `react-alert-template-basic`. It's a simple template file that you can keep in your codebase. You can copy all the things from `react-alert-template-basic` except `width` (which is set to `300px`) and you're good to go.
2. Keep using `react-alert-template-basic` but override CSS. You'll have to use `!important` to override as they are using inline styles.

Like this

```css
#__react-alert__ div div div {
  width: auto !important;
}
```

Comment: can we change the css styles based on error,success. Suppose the alert was error i need to change background color to red and if the alert was success the background color should be green. is this possible?